# What is the difference between Spark's Partition Pruning and Predicate Pushdown?

Tags: apache-spark

I was going through Spark optimization methods and came across various ways to implement to achieve optimization. But two names caught my eyes.

1. Partition Pruning
2. Predicate Pushdown

They say:

Partition Pruning:

> Partition pruning is a performance optimization that limits the number
>   of files and partitions that Spark reads when querying. After
>   partitioning the data, queries that match certain partition filter
>   criteria improve performance by allowing Spark to only read a subset
>   of the directories and files.

Predicate Pushdown:

> Spark will attempt to move filtering of data as close to the source as
>   possible to avoid loading unnecessary data into memory. Parquet and
>   ORC files maintain various stats about each column in different chunks
>   aof data (such as min and max values). Programs reading these files
>   can use these indexes to determine if certain chunks, and even entire
>   files, need to be read at all.  This allows programs to potentially
>   skip over huge portions of the data during processing.

By reading the above concepts, they appear to do the same thing which is to apply read statements (queries) that satisfy the predicates given in the query.
Are Partition Pruning and Predicate Pushdown different concepts or I'm looking at them in a wrong way?

Comment: Predicate pushdowns may result in partition prunings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58140612/spark-predicate-push-down-filtering-and-partition-pruning-for-azure-data-lake

Answer (score 3):

The difference is about who applies the optimization, where the optimization is applied and which data sources it can be applied to.

- Partition pruning is applied by Spark itself before it delegates to a data source handling the file format. It's only applicable in the case of file-based formats as data sources don't have the concept of partition discovery (yet).
- Predicate push down delegates filtering of rows to the data source responsible for handling a particular format (Spark's term for a type of data source). Predicate push down is available for both file-based and non-file-based sources, e.g., RDBMS and NoSQL databases.

Comment: can you please provide reference of statements.  I agree that predicate pushdown applicable for file as well as DB. But i am not sure about partition pruning applies to files only. I saw some notes that this applies to data source but nowhere mentioned about file specifically.

Comment: please have look on https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0-preview/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/dynamicpruning/PartitionPruning.html

Answer (score 0):

Predicate Pushdown is a technique where filters, or predicates, are pushed down to the storage layer of a database management system. This way, only the relevant data is retrieved from the storage layer, reducing the amount of data that needs to be processed and thus improving the performance of the query. By pushing down the predicates, the database system can take advantage of any indexing or other optimization that is present at the storage layer.

Column Pruning is a technique where unnecessary columns are removed from the query processing pipeline. This can improve the performance of a query by reducing the amount of data that needs to be processed, stored in memory, and transferred over the network. The database system determines which columns are necessarily based on the query, and removes the unused columns before the query is executed.

Both Predicate Pushdown and Column Pruning are important optimization techniques that are used in modern database systems to improve query performance and make efficient use of available resources.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but the current answers can be refined:

> At the high-level, partition pruning and predicate pushdown are indeed the same thing; however partition pruning (if possible) takes it one step further.

Both optimizations happen as spark generates an execution plan and before any data is loaded. The mantra is "the fastest way to process data is not to process data".

Predicate pushdown happens when we can move a `filter` statement from a later stage into an earlier one. This discards irrelevant data asap and means we have less volume to scatter during the shuffle between stages (aka its faster).

Partition pruning happens when we can move a `filter` statement to "stage 0", i.e., the stage that loads data into spark. We combine the filter with file metadata to deduce if we can skip loading the file alltogether and thus have to do 0 work on it.

Note that databricks (or rather delta tables) differentiate between two types of "partition pruning": (1) Partition pruning, which uses a`filter` to remove entire folders based on the folder name, and (2) file skipping, which uses a `filter` to remove individual data files based on file metadata.