# Spark pushdown filter without partition column performance

Tags: apache-spark

I have a question regarding the filtering in spark when you do not include the partition columns in the filter.

Imagine that I have the following data partitioned by date:

```
path/date=20200721/part-0000.parquet
                   part-0001.parquet
                   part-0002.parquet
path/date=20200722/part-0000.parquet
                   part-0001.parquet
                   part-0002.parquet
...
```

And the data have one column named "action" which around 30% of the data have a value of 0 and the rest of the data value of 1

If I run the following:

```
spark.read.parquet("s3a://path").filter("action = 0")
```

Does spark have to list and scan all the files located in "path" from the source? Or there is some pushdown filtering in place? Or spark only applies a pushdown filter where a partition column is present in the filter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> 1.Does spark have to list and scan all the files located in "path" from
> the source?

**`Yes`**, as you are not filtering on partition column spark list and scan all files

> 2.There is some pushdown filtering in place?

There will be **`pushdown filter`** applied on each files while reading

> 3.spark only applies a pushdown filter where a partition column is
> present in the filter?

**`No`**, Partition filter will be applied where a partition column present or else predicate pushdown will be applied while scanning the file.

[**`partition filter vs pushdown filter`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58140612/spark-predicate-push-down-filtering-and-partition-pruning-for-azure-data-lake)

- You can check all these details by checking explain plan in spark `.explain(true)`

To check if filter pushdown **`enabled or not`**:

```
spark.sql("set spark.sql.parquet.filterPushdown").show(10,false)
//+--------------------------------+-----+
//|key                             |value|
//+--------------------------------+-----+
//|spark.sql.parquet.filterPushdown|true |
//+--------------------------------+-----+
```